# Why do the shutdown and startup scripts placed at /etc/init.d/ not run on shutting down or during startup?

Tags: ubuntu, sysvinit, rc

I basically have a simple script

```
#!/bin/sh
sudo echo "process kill" >> /home/logfile
```

placed at `etc/init.d/lokill`
and symbolic links K99lokill to `/etc/init.d/lokill` placed at `/etc/rc0.d` and `/etc/rc6.d`

But after I restart the system ,the logfile is not even created.
I've created similar script and put symbolic links in rc2.d ,rc3.d and rc4.d with S99 prefix but even that does not work..

Comment: Why are you using `sudo`? The script is supposed to be run as `root`.

Comment: Sorry , I didn't know that